# set position of each instance according to a formula

Tags: node-editor

I'm sure I'm butchering things so I'm sorry in advance.
I'm trying to create "bricks" and I want to offset each vertical edge (or vertex along vertical axis y in this case)
I want each iteration of instances to apply that formula and displace edges/vertices randomly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]It's not exactly what I want to do "mathematically" but it does what I want it to do.
I ended up instancing the squares then I set position by using a noise and put Index output into the noise's vector (not 100% sure what this does and how I can control this)
I still am very curious if it is possible to do what I asked for in the original question